# scene node transform order

Tags: ogre

I have a simple question, in scene graph implemention. A scene node record transform info relation parent scene node. As we know, The full transform matrix is built by Trans(local) * Trans(parent) * Trans(root). The local transform matrix is create from translation, scale and rotation, and the order is SRT, scale * rotation * translation. But now I have a model, it is not modeled at its geometry center. So before apply rotation to rotate the model, we need to apply a local space translation, translate the origin to geometry center first, then we can rotate around any axis. In this case, we need a transform order translate * rotate, not the default rotate * translate.

Question is in Ogre like engine, how to rotation scene node which attaches the model as i describe above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved myself. First, create a scene node which is used to translate to model center. The model is attached to this scene node. Then do whatever you want, the scene node we created before is a child of any other normal scene node.